# Can't get property dependency injection to work in React project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dependency-injection, inversifyjs

I need some really basic dependency injection for a react project in a similar syntactical manner as in C# or Java. Using context or injection through props is not an option. I tried three solutions so far:

- [Inversify](https://github.com/inversify)
- [Inversify-React-Decorators](https://github.com/inversify/inversify-inject-decorators)
- [React.DI](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/react.di)

However, none of theses solutions worked, which raised the questions if there is some sort of configuration issue.

**Using Inversify / Inversify-React-Decorators / Rect.DI**

SomeService.ts

```
import { inject, injectable } from "inversify";
import { TYPES, ITokenProvider, IFileService } from "../injectables";
import { lazyInject, DIContainer } from "../inversify.config";

export class SomeService {

    @inject(TYPES.ITokenProvider) private tokenProvider!: ITokenProvider;      //Inversify
    //@lazyInject(TYPES.ITokenProvider) private tokenProvider!: ITokenProvider;//Inversify-r-d
    //@Inject tokenProvider!: TokenProvider;                                   //react-di
     (...)
}
```

inversify.config.ts

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { Container } from "inversify";
import getDecorators from "inversify-inject-decorators";

import { TYPES, ITokenProvider, } from "./injectables";
import { TokenProvider } from "./Services/TokenProvider"


const DIContainer = new Container();
DIContainer.bind<ITokenProvider>(TYPES.ITokenProvider).toConstructor(TokenProvider);


const { lazyInject } = getDecorators(DIContainer, false);

export { DIContainer, lazyInject }
```

injectables.ts

```
export interface ITokenProvider {
    getSomeToken(): Promise<string>
}
```

TokenProvider.ts

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import * as microsoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js";

import { injectable } from "inversify";
import { ITokenProvider } from '../injectables';

@injectable()
export class TokenProvider implements ITokenProvider {

    public constructor() { }

    public async getSomeToken(): Promise<string> {
        (...)
    }
}
```

App.tsx (used by react-di instead of inversify.config)

```
@Module({
    providers: [
        { provide: AccessTokenProvider, useClass: AccessTokenProvider },
    ]
})
```

**Errors**

React-DI and Inversify won'r resolve the dependency, causing an undefined error for the property.
Inversify decorators causes following error:

```
TokenProvider.ts:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'SomeService' before initialization
    at Module.SomeService (VM8 main.chunk.js:248)
    at Module../src/inversify.config.ts (inversify.config.ts:11)
   (...)
```

**Config**

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "include": [
    "src/*"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "types": [ "reflect-metadata" ]
  }
}
```

I also tried moving the `"reflect-metadata"` around different classes.

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Nested @lazyInject not working :https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/issues/941

---

The problem exists because of a circular dependency between a class (in the case above, the Header class) and the `inversify.config'.` inversify.config `needs to import` Headerin order to create the bindings but Header needs access to lazy Inject which is created `ininversify.config`.

The solution is to split your existing i`nversify.config` into three files.

Does nothing except create the container (in my case it is called `container.ts`)
Imports the container from the previous file and adds the bindings (in my case named `inversify.config.ts`)
Imports file 1 (not 2!), calls getDecorators() and exports lazyInject
Your class would then import lazyInject from that third file instead of `inversify.config`.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32603164)